# Selecting rows based on values in one of its semi-colon delimited columns: PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently trying to select all rows where a certain ID exists within that rows semi-colon delimited ID column.

The Table:

```
=====================
 TOOL_ID | TOOL_USERS
---------------------
    1        1;2;3
    2        1;3
    3        1
=====================
```

I want to select all the tools that a certain user has access to, for example, the desired result where the user ID is 3:

```
TOOL_ID | TOOL_USERS
---------------------
    1        1;2;3
    2        1;3
```

I know that this design is not normalized, but I do not have the ability to change/modify the database. I could always just query all of the rows and then loop through the results deleting any that don't contain the user id, but I'd rather do this is one nice, clean query.

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: One thing you have to consider is, that the entries in TOOL_USERS can be "2;11;21" and not all ids have an semi-colon bevor the id nor after the id. So you have to look that you don't get false positives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the LIKE keyword with wildcards.  I included leading and ending semicolons so 13 and stuff doesn't match 3.

```
SELECT TOOL_ID, TOOL_USERS FROM YourTable WHERE ';' || TOOL_USERS || ';' LIKE '%;3;%'
```

Someone let me know if I didn't translate this well to PLSQL.

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator in Oracle.